# Como melhorar a performance da consulta Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, desempenho

Tenho a consulta linq abaixo

```
var f = (from l in fpcList
join fpp in FPP on new { l.fpId, l.etId } equals new { fpp.fpId, fpp.etId }
join fpcp in FPCP on fpp.fppId equals fpcp.fppId
select new { fpp.fppId, fpp.fpId, fpp.etId, fpcp.ecId }).ToList();
```

A lista fpcList possui uns 24 itens normalmente

A tabela FPP possui mais de 200.000 itens

A Tabela FPCP possui mais 600.000 itens

A consulta está lenta, sou programador iniciante e se alguém souber outra forma de efetuar a mesma, agradeço.

## SOLUÇÃO (10-07-2019)

Posto pois pode auxiliar outros programadores! Fiz primeiro a consulta ao Banco de Dados e após apliquei os filtros da lista. A performance melhorou significamente.

```
var f= (from fpp in FPP
join fpcp in FPCP on fpp.fppId equals fpcp.fppId
select new { fpp.fppId , fpp.fpId, fpp.etId, fpcp.ecId}).AsEnumerable()
.Where(y => fpcList.Any(x => x.fpId == y.fpId && x.etId == y.etId ))
.Select(x => new { x.fppId, x.fpId, x.etId, x.ecId}).ToList();
```

Muito obrigado a todos

Comment: Você precisa de todos os itens duma só vez?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem várias coisas que podem ser feitas para melhoria de performance ai.

Exemplos:

> 1) Criar indices no banco de dados (caso não existam) para fpId+ etId
>   na FPP  e também para fppId na FPCP . [Como Criar Indice no sql server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-nonclustered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> 2) Trazer somente os campos que vai utilizar antes de dar um ToList.
>
> 3) Se for um site MVC e estiver enviando os dados para uma view, não
>   usar o ToList. Envie o model sem tolist para view e receba como um
>   IEnumarable na view
>
> 4) Ainda, se for apresentar os dados em um site, usar paginação e não
>   pegar todos os dados como está fazendo. Pegar todos os dados deixa
>   realmente lento. Neste caso, se for usar paginação é mais eficiente
>   fazer isto através de procedure. Exemplo de como fazer paginação no
>   Sql Server [aqui](https://www.sqlservergeeks.com/t-sql-paging-stored-procedure/)

```
var f = (from l in fpcList
join fpp in FPP on new { l.fpId, l.etId } equals new { fpp.fpId, fpp.etId }
join fpcp in FPCP on fpp.fppId equals fpcp.fppId
select new { fpp.fppId, fpp.fpId, fpp.etId, fpcp.ecId })
.Select(x => x new {CampoA = x.CampoA, CampoB = x.CampoB}).ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado Elizeu! Vou efetuar algumas alterações que me orientou e posto aqui o resultado ...

Answer (score 3):

O problema não é com o Linq em si, e sim com a forma que você está fazendo a consulta no banco de dados.

Caso você esteja trabalhando com Entity, veja no *output* do seu *debug* a SQL que está sendo gerada e tente executar ela diretamente no banco de dados e analise a performance. Verifique no seu banco de dados se as relações `on new { l.fpId, l.etId } equals new { fpp.fpId, fpp.etId }` e `on fpp.fppId equals fpcp.fppId` estão bem feitas (existe o índice de ForeingKey para essas relações?).

Feito isso, considere mesmo se você tem a necessidade de trazer todos esses dados de uma vez (como comentado por *CypherPotato*), adicione mais filtros como um período de Data por exemplo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sim são ForeignKey ... vou rever .... Muito obrigado!